# GPL: distribute compiled binary

Tags: software, open-source-software, gpl

Is it legal to modify GPL v3.0 content and distribute a binary of the remixed content without disclosing the modified source code?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [opensource.se]. In brief: no, you can't do that. The GPL only gives you the right to modify and distribute the software under the condition that you also give every recipient the Corresponding Source of your modified version.

Comment: basically the whole point of the GPL is that this is illegal

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you is to distribute source code and compiled code *together*. That way you have fulfilled all your GPL obligations and you have no requirement to do anything for anyone in the future.

The alternative is to distribute the compiled code, together with an offer valid for three years to supply the source code on request to *anyone* ever asking for it. So distributing without supplying the source code *right now* is legal, but you *must* supply it later when requested.

Comment: The GPL-3.0 restricts the "written offer" mechanism to cases where a non-commercial recipient passes on someone else's written offer (not applicable here), or where the object code is distributed via a physical medium (e.g. CD-ROM, or part of a physical product like a car, vacuum cleaner robot, IoT sensor, …). If the object code is offered for download, then the Corresponding Source MUST be available for download through the same place (e.g. by providing a link to the source).